# Problems with 12.04 // Problemas con 12.04

Tags: 12.04

Tengo una Acer Aspire 5520-3992, AMD Turion 64, con tarjeta Nvidia
Primeramente actualicé de 11.10 a la versión 12.04 y no funcionó correctamente. Una vez que me identifico, las pantallas están totalmente negras, lo mas que logro es ver algunas carpetas pero sin os botones de cerrar, maximizar, etc. posteriormente hice una instalación de cero para ver si evitaba estos problemas y obtuve los mismos resultados, aparentemente tiene algún problema con los controladores gráficos.

Cualquier ayuda la agradeceré, antes de regresarme a la 11.10 con la cual no tenía problemas.

Gerardo Granados

**TRANSLATION:**

*I own an Acer Aspire 5520-3992, AMD Turion 64, with an nVidia graphics card. I first updated from 11.10 to 12.04 and it didn't work correctly. Once I have logged in, screens become absolutely blank, the most I can see is some folders but no close, maximize and other buttons. Later I made a fresh install from scratch in order to see if this corrected these problems and I got the same results. Apparently there is a kind of a problem with graphics drivers.*

*Any help is really appreciated, I am planning to downgrade to 11.10 on which I didn't experience any problems at all.*

*Gerardo Granados*

Comment: I did a Google translate on this question found here: I have an Acer Aspire 5520-3992 AMD Turion 64, First Nvidia card upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 version and did not work properly. Once I identify with, the screens are completely black, as much as achievement is to see some folders but you buttons to close, maximize, etc. then did a clean install to see if it avoided these problems and got the same results, apparently has a problem with graphics drivers.

Any help the grateful, before back onto the 11.10 with which he had no problems.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

Pienso que, probablamente, tú necesitas instalar los controladores propietarios de hardware. Busque en "Additional Hardware Drivers". Yo no sé.

English Translation by Google Translate:

"I think that, you probably, you need to install the proprietary drivers for hardware. Look in "Additional Hardware Drivers". I do not know."

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, pero eso fue lo primero que hice y no obtuve resultados. Mejor me regresé a la 11.10